# Use Regular expression in JSX file in (React + Material-ui)

Tags: javascript, regex, formsy-material-ui

I am trying to use RegEx to do material-ui form based validation. I am using my JS based Regex, but it does not work. Why ?

Below is the snippet from my template.jsx file. my-form is just a wrapper on the formsy material-ui component.

```
import {myForm, TextField} from '@react-component/my-form';

export default (props) => {
 } = props;
   const emailRegex = new RegExp('/\S+@\S+\.\S+/');
    const phoneRegEx = new RegExp('/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-/\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/');
    return (
<myForm>
  <TextField id="smsNumber" value={userInfo.smsNumber} name="smsNumberName" required requiredError="Mobile is a required field." validations={{matchRegexp:phoneRegEx}} validationErrors={{matchRegexp:'Enter a valid mobile.'}} onChange={changeSmsNumber} floatingLabelText={t('userProfile.mobile', "Mobile")} floatingLabelFixed={true} hintText={t('userProfile.mobile', "Mobile")}/>
</myForm>
   );
};
```

This code always gives 'Enter a valid Mobile' error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a regex literal notation and anchor the email regex:

```
 const emailRegex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
                    ^^            ^^
```

And this is a `phoneRegEx` fix:

```
const phoneRegEx = /^[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-/\s.]?[0-9]{4}$/;
```

Note that `{0,1}` limiting quantifier is the same as `?` (*1 or 0 occurrences*). There is no need escaping a dot inside `[...]` character class, it already matches a literal dot there.

Comment: Can you help me how to place variable in regex in react, 
ex: `var re1 = new RegExp("^--" + boundary + "$", "gm");`

Comment: @ViswaTejaKuncham Not sure what problem you have, but it should be at least `var re1 = new RegExp("^--" + boundary.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "$");`. Not sure what flags you use though.