# Regular Expression for negative and positive decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression using javascript for react application that allow negative and positive decimal numbers and not allow enter any character.

I've been looking for examples, reading documentation but I dont know how make it.

This are the things that have to do:

allow negative and positive decimal numbers, I found this:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[+-]?[0-9]{0,900}(?:\.[0-9]{0,900})?$");
```

but I can write a character and show me true and add other character and show me false. `console.log(re.test(value));`

if is decimal and starts with zero show zero (0.232) and dont allow this (.232)

dont allow write characters, I've seen this `/^\d*$/`

Comment: Do you actually want to limit to 900 digits?

Comment: looks like duplicate from the following [quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460773/regex-validate-negative-and-positive-decimal-numbers/16461060)

Comment: For "allow negative and positive decimal numbers and not allow enter any character" try this : ^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$

Comment: no, I dont want a limit of digits... and I'm using an input type text and I dont want allow characters and not use a type number

Comment: @JaviLesPaul you just wanna make sure your input type `text` only gets numbed in it right ?

Comment: You need to double  escape `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) it states that when using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.

Your regex would then match a dot which would match any character making for example `a` valid because the preceding `[0-9]{0,900}` matches zero - 900 times.

Your regex would become:

```
var re = new RegExp("^[+-]?[0-9]{0,900}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,900})?$");
```

To match negative and positive decimal numbers  that should not start with a dot, you could use:

[`^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/riHmIP/1)

Which will match the beginning of the string `^`,  an optional `[+-]?`, one or more digits `[0-9]+` followed by an optional part which will match a dot and one or more digits `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` and then the end of the string `$`.

```
var re = new RegExp("^-?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?$");
```

```js
var re = new RegExp("^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?$");
var strings = [
  "1",
  "1.2",
  "0.232",
  ".232",
  "-1.2",
  "+1.2"

];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + re.test(s));
});
```

Comment: look here https://regex101.com/r/OREez0/1, in your function works but using react onChange doesnt work

Comment: @JaviLesPaul Perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883057/use-regular-expression-in-jsx-file-in-react-material-ui) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

- only numbers
- positive and negative
- dont allow .232

Comment: you can shorten `[0-9]\d*` to `\d+`. OP also wanted to allow a leading `+`, so you might as well allow that